# Python Selenium, how to try multiple values if login fails

Tags: python, selenium

Here i have stored two separate passwords for the script to try if the first fails. However, i'm having an issue adding the "else" statement which is what I (a Noob) think is required. Or is there a better way?

```
try:
        browser.get(url) #Browse to all IPs from opened file
        WebDriverWait(browser,2).until(EC.title_is("Login")) #Wait until title of the CPE is loaded(Helps to determine if IP is connected)
        username = browser.find_element_by_name("username")
        password = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
        username.send_keys(credentials.usrn)
        password.send_keys(credentials.pswd2, Keys.ENTER)
        if WebDriverWait(browser, 1).until(EC.alert_is_present()): #If password incorrect, wait for popup alert and clear it then try new password
            popup = browser.switch_to.alert
            popup.accept()
            username = browser.find_element_by_name("username")
            password = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
            username.send_keys(credentials.usrn)
            password.send_keys(credentials.pswd, Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: What error are you getting??

Comment: With respect to the little info you have provided about your usecase i think replacing `if`with a `try-catch{}` block will be of more help .

Comment: I'm attempting to scrape serial numbers from a list of devices i have connected to my network. All devices are the same but not all of them have the same password for their admin page. I'm aware of the different passwords used on the devices, but i'm not sure which has which. So basically i was thinking some what of a brute force method to try each string in a list if the other fails. I've succeeded in trying two, hence my try and if statements.

Comment: since you are aware of the passwords for each device, how about identifying the devices by name (or something else) and passing the credentials accordingly to login.

Comment: problem is i'm not quite sure how to tell python to try password one password, if error, try the other, if error again try the last.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do it is check to see whether the login was a success via the URL, and if it's not, then move onto the if clause.
I'm going to use Instagram as an example.

First you need to find what a successful login URL looks like.

```
successful_url = "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/onetap/?next=%2F"
```

Now we will try to login and grab the URL after we enter the information.

```
username = browser.find_element_by_name("username")
password = browser.find_element_by_name("password")
username.send_keys(credentials.usrn)
password.send_keys(credentials.pswd2, Keys.ENTER)
check_url = browser.current_url #returns a string with the current url
```

Now we check to see if we should enter the next value.

```
if check_url != successful_url:
    username.send_keys(credentials.usrn)
    password.send_keys(credentials.pswd, Keys.ENTER)
    check_url = browser.current_url #recheck the url
```

Additionally, I would recommend using a loop because a loop will run until you are logged in, otherwise you will need to use different if statements. You cannot add an `else/elif` clause to this as it will run the first `if` and ignore the rest (just like any `if` statement in Python, assuming you use the same condition to check to see if you have a successful login.)